# Restlet - Status service driven by the requested resource

Tags: restlet, status

I am developing for the following REST inquiries with [Restlet](http://restlet.com/).

```
http://localhost:8182/employees/{empId}
http://localhost:8182/timeline/{empId}
```

I have an application with an overridden `createInbounRoot` that has a `Router` attached to `employees/{empId}` and `timeline/{empId}`. In this application, I am able to set one status service, say `EmployeeStatusService`. How do I tell my application to use a different status service depending on the resource requested ?

Or, is there a completely different way of doing this ?

My application:

```
public class App1 extends Application {

    public CatalogueApplication() {
        this.setStatusService(new EmployeeStatusService());
        //this.setStatusService(new TimelineStatusService());
    }

   @Override
    public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
        Router router = new Router(getContext());
        router.attach("/employees/{empId}", Employees.class);
        router.attach("/timeline/{empId}", Timeline.class);
        return router;
    }

}
```

Comment: I can't recommend a different way to do something without more detail as to what that something is, although my initial vague  impression is that I would potentially use a pair of custom `Filter` objects overriding `afterHandle()` applied to each path rather than any `StatusService`s as the framework assumes no more than one `StatusService` per `Application` object.  If you really need multiple StatusServices, look at a `Component` containing multiple Applications?  Again I can't recommend either option, in your use case.

Comment: Basically, my aim is to have different status services based on URI pattern as requested. I was under the impression that, I could toggle between status services based on URI pattern.

The option of a component with multiple applications is something that I would like to try out.

Thanks for your response !